CNN: Accuracy gap of 5-7 % between accuracy computed on-the-fly and separate model evaluation on the training set
I am training a CNN for some basic classification task. During training, I compute the training accuracy after every epoch. After the training has finished, I evaluate the model again on the entire training set (and compute additional metrics). I noticed a gap in the accuracy scores between the accuracy as I compute it after the epoch and the accuracy when evaluating the model on the entire training set in one go.Now of course, during training, the model can improve across the batches. So it is to be expected that the training accuracy of the model AFTER finishing the epoch will be greater then the "average accuracy" during the epoch. BUT, this behavior persists even in later epochs, where training accuracy increases only rather slowly. Even then I see a difference of between 5-7 %. This seems weird to me and I'd like to figure out why this occurs and if I perhaps do something wrong!
Here is the code I am using:
def TrainCNN(model,  train_set,  valid_set, training_params, outpath):
    loss_function = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=training_params['lr0'], weight_decay=training_params['l2'])

    train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=training_params['batch_size'], shuffle=True)
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(outpath, patience=5, verbose=True)

    metrics = training_params['metrics'] #{'balanced_accuracy':balanced_accuracy_score, 'accuracy':accuracy_score}
    scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, mode='min', factor=0.25, patience=3)

    for epoch in range(0, training_params['epochs']):
        train_accuracy, avg_loss = TrainOneEpoch(model, train_loader, loss_function, optimizer, l1_lambda=training_params['l1'])
        valid_metrics_scores = EvaluateModel(model, valid_set, metrics)
        early_stopping(-valid_metrics_scores["balanced_accuracy"], model)
        scheduler.step(-valid_metrics_scores["balanced_accuracy"])

        if early_stopping.early_stop:
            print("Stopping training due to no increase in validation accuracy...")
            break

        print(f"Epoch {epoch}: Train {train_accuracy * 100} % Accuracy")
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}: Valid {valid_metrics_scores['balanced_accuracy'] * 100} % Balanced Accuracy")

    final_train_metrics = EvaluateModel(model, train_set, metrics)


    return model, final_train_metrics, valid_metrics_scores



def TrainOneEpoch(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, l1_lambda):
    model.train()
    device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
    model.to(device)

    correct_train = 0
    total_loss = 0.0
    size = len(train_loader.dataset)
    for batch, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        pred = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(pred, labels)
        l1_norm = sum(p.abs().sum() for fc_block in model.fc_blocks[:-1] for p in fc_block.parameters())
        loss = loss + l1_lambda * l1_norm
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        correct_train += (pred.argmax(1) == labels).type(torch.float).sum().item()
        total_loss += loss.item()

        if batch % train_loader.batch_size == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), batch * len(inputs)
            print(f'loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]')

    train_accuracy = correct_train / size
    avg_loss = total_loss / size  # average loss for the entire dataset

    return train_accuracy, avg_loss

def GetPredictions(model, dataset, batch_size=128):
    data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size)
    device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

    all_predictions =  []
    all_labels      = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, labels in data_loader:
            inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
            outputs = model(inputs)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs,1)

            all_predictions.append(predicted.cpu())
            all_labels.append(labels.cpu())

    all_predictions = torch.cat(all_predictions)
    all_labels = torch.cat(all_labels)

    return  all_predictions, all_labels


def EvaluateModel(model, dataset, metrics, batch_size=128):
    model.eval()
    device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
    model.to(device)
    predictions, labels = GetPredictions(model, dataset, batch_size)

    metric_scores = {}
    for metric_name, metric in metrics.items():
        score = metric(labels, predictions)
        metric_scores[metric_name] = score

    return metric_scores

The difference I am talking about is the diffence between the accuracy computed here
train_accuracy = correct_train / size

and the accuracy computed here (among other metrics):
predictions, labels = GetPredictions(model, dataset, batch_size)

metric_scores = {}
for metric_name, metric in metrics.items():
    score = metric(labels, predictions)
    metric_scores[metric_name] = score

The metrics I am using are these (from sklearn):
def BuildMetrics():
    f1_score_weighted = lambda y_true, y_pred: f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted')
    precision_score_weighted = lambda y_true, y_pred: precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted')
    recall_score_weighted = lambda y_true, y_pred: recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted')
    metrics = {'balanced_accuracy': balanced_accuracy_score, 'accuracy': accuracy_score, 'F1': f1_score_weighted,
               'recall': recall_score_weighted, 'precision': precision_score_weighted, 'confusion_matrix':confusion_matrix}
    return metrics

My CNN uses dropout in one of the fully connected layers. However, deactivated dropout cannot (!) explain this issue, as I get the same  accuracy using the accuracy_score function using the model in train and eval mode. I just tested exactly this one after the other while debugging.
